# Rkt pod exited immediately (without logs)

Tags: linux, rkt, rocket

I am currently trying to run a ubuntu rkt pod. It seems to work well with the *--interactive* option, but when I ask for a simple run without interaction, the pod exits immediately...
I don't have any log (*--no entries--*) when I checked with *journalctl*
I just have an exited status.

The image is just an ACI that I got through docker://ubuntu and gave to docker2aci. What I don't understand is that it works well in interactive mode...

- Command used to run the pod:

  `sudo rkt --interactive --insecure-options=image run XXXXXXX.aci`
- Command to get the image:

  `sudo docker2aci docker://ubuntu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found what was going on. This is just a problem with the run command. *run* have to come right after *rkt*. i know, it's stupid, but I may not be the only one facing this.
The right command :

```
sudo rkt run --insecure-options=image XXXXXXX.aci
```